# SSL and CNAMEs?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, cname-record

I have a question. We are using a CNAME on our server to direct to an application we host on another server. Which server would I install the SSL certificate on for that cloud application? We would need to use the CNAME host name. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SSL Certificate gets issued for whatever the user types into their browser.

If the user types in `www.example.com`, then you need a cert for "www.example.com"
It does not matter how DNS looks up the server, CNAME, A records, whatever.

The Certificate gets installed on the web server. There would be only one in the scenario you described.