# Adding SSL for a domain name using a CNAME record

Tags: ssl

I'm hosting a website with Fortrabbit. I point `subdomain.mywebsite.com` to `mywebapp.eu1.frbit.net` using a CNAME record, next I wanted to add ssl.

I created a certificate signing request and applied for a certificate using the following:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -keyout my-app.key -out my-app.csr -newkey rsa:2048
```

I've just received my certificate and have entered it in the admin panel, but visiting the `subdomain.mywebsite.com` gives me the following:

```
subdomain.mywebsite.com uses an invalid security certificate.

The certificate is only valid for *.eu1.frbit.net

(Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)
```

Have I entered details in the Certificate request incorrectly?

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:GB
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:London
Locality Name (eg, city) []:London
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:My Website
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:subdomain.mywebsite.com
Email Address []:admin@mywebsite.com

Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:
An optional company name []:My Website Ltd
```

#### Edit

Looking at this [SSL and CNAMEs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/318386/ssl-and-cnames) I think I have it right, but the results say otherwise.

Comment: Looks like you are seeing completely different certificate. 1) have you installed the one the CSR is for ? 2) If yes, - what does the `openssl x509 -in <your certificate> -noout -text` say abount the CN of the certificate ? 3) are there any other sites on this IP ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a SSL certificate only allows one Common Name (CN). You can add one or more Alternative Names (SANs) to a SSL certificate, but most CA's charge more to sign those certificates and your browser or application needs to understand SAN (although all modern web browsers do so).